# The meaning of "もの" in this sentence

Tags: particles

> その地域では今も戦争で日に**何人もの人**が死んでいる。

I encountered the above sentence. But, if it were me, I would write something like this:

> その地域では今も 戦争で(日々or日)に**何人も**死んでいる。

Is there any difference between the two in terms of meaning? Moreover, is there any other example containing "何XものX" (X could be 人 or other words)?

Thanks for your reply in advance.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/56819/why-is-%e3%81%ae-used-in-%e4%bd%95%e5%8d%81%e3%82%82%e3%81%ae/56825#56825

Comment: You're parsing it wrong; it's non 何人もの(人), it's 何人も(の人). も in this context is used to show that there is a large number/amount of something.

Answer (score 0):

何人もの人 means simply many people. It could be tens, hundreds, thousands, or even more.
何人も could probably mean several people, 10 at most.
If you would like to describe things rather than people, "いくつもの" (many) and "いくつも" (several) are for you.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it's 「何人 もの 人」. I think it's 「何人も の 人」 which I think translates literally to "every person."

According to [Jisho](http://jisho.org/search/%E4%BD%95%E4%BA%BA%E3%82%82), 何人も is a noun that translates to "everyone/all/nobody." And, 何人も was brought up in [an older post](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/19374/27969), where a user paraphrased it as だれも, which can also be interpreted as "everyone/no one."

So I think the sentence can be translated to something along the lines of "Here in this war, even now, many people are dying."

Comment: I think this answer was most likely downvoted because it contains incorrect information.  I don't think it's correct to say that 「何人もの人」 translates to "every person".

Comment: @Yana `According to Jisho, 何人も is a noun that translates to "everyone/all/nobody."` <-- その「何人も」は「なん**びと**も/なん**ぴと**も」(anyone) です。「何人もの人」の「何人」は「なん**にん** 」(how many people) です。（「なにじん」は what nationality）読み方も意味も違います